# Override methods from traits in case objects

Tags: scala

I have a trait and two case objects. Both case objects have an almost identical method which utilises one unique method from the case object. I want to extract the identical method and place it in the trait. I am unsure how to do that with the unique methods it takes in as arguments. Code example:

```
sealed trait Book {}

case object Page extends Book {
def a(): UniqueToPage = println("Page")
def shared(contents: String) = println(s"Something shared and ${a()} and $contents") 
}

case object Cover extends Book {
def b(): UniqueToCover = println("Cover")
def shared(contents: String) = println(s"Something shared and ${b()} and $contents")
}
```

It seems to me that perhaps there is something I could do with type conversion but I am at loss as to where to start. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please note that the design is part of a larger project and I am trying to refactor this specific part.

Comment: There isn't enough detail to give sensible answers. For example in this code both `a` and `b` return `Unit` so there is no point in calling them in `shared` at all. So *for this code* it is easy to put `shared` in the trait, but I'm guessing that the real code is not that simple.

Comment: A `println` doesn't return a **UniqueToCover**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It does if `UniqueToCover >: Unit` :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No I meant `UniqueToCover >: Unit` as I wrote. With `UniqueToCover <: Unit` `def b(): UniqueToCover = println("Cover")` will not compile. I guess you confuse inheritance and subtyping. `Unit` is final but can have subtypes.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I can return `AnyVal`, `Any`. I don't have to create supertypes or subtypes, they are. `AnyVal`, `Any`, `T >: Unit` (and `Unit ∨ X` in Dotty) are supertypes of `Unit`. `Nothing`, `Unit with Y`, `T <: Unit` are subtypes of Unit.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez also `x.type` (for `val x = ()`) is a subtype of `Unit` (different from `Unit`).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't think this discussion leads anywhere. How does [this](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/6a98cee065355d226fd319f2b1246941) break Liskov? In my setting `UniqueToPage` is not a type alias, it's abstract. Surely I can create a new type which is a subtype of `Unit`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin oh right I confused what you were trying to say. I thought you suggested `def foo: Unit = (() : Any)` which obviously don't make sense, but obviously isn't what you said. Sorry, I need a break. I am deleting all my previous comments to avoid the noise.

Comment: My apologies, the println statements was a rather poor way to show the relationship between the methods. You can assume that the specified return types of those methods are what is actually returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If methods `a()` and `b()` return different types `UniqueToPage` and `UniqueToCover` try to introduce type member

```
sealed trait Book {
  type T
  def c(): T
  def shared(contents: String) = println(s"Something shared and ${c()} and $contents")
}

case object Page extends Book {
  override type T = UniqueToPage
  override def c(): T = println("Page")
}

case object Cover extends Book {
  override type T = UniqueToCover
  override def c(): T = println("Cover")
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works because `${c()}` calls `toString` and this is available on every type `T`. A real-world example would have to constrain `T` to a supertype of `UniqueToPage` and `UniqueToCover` that had the common methods that were required by `Book`.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you so much for your help! You're a wonderful human being!